# How to connect my android device from a vm? (vm -> local desktop -> android device (usb))

Tags: android, debugging, adb

How can I connect my android device from my development vm (adb devices)? The android device is connected on my local desktop via usb.

Comment: Use this https://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html and this http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html together.

Comment: Of course I take adb - but for what is the second one?